# Facebook debugger authentication

Tags: facebook, debugging, authentication

I need to scrap a URL with server authentication. I've tried to pass login and password in URL like: `http://login:password@example.com` but no succeed. Any idea if its possible to pass the authentication on Facebook Debugger?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, the debug tool does not support that - the URLs you provide to Facebook need to be reachable by Facebook's crawler if you want it to pull metadata from those URLs